# Number guesser game generates a different numbers each guess

Tags: java, jsp, random

I have a Java Server Page that lets the user pick a number of their choice from 1-1000. The page then uses the number entered and finds out if the number matches the number that is generated. -- Pictures below if ^ is unclear. Currently, the program generates a different number each time the user guesses a number -- whether it is correct or not. How do I make it so that the program only generates a number when the user either refreshes the page or guesses correctly?

JSP code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import = "Chapter12.RandomGuess" %>
<jsp:useBean id = "randomGuessId" class = "Chapter12.RandomGuess" scope = "page" >
</jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty name = "randomGuessId" property = "*" />
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Guess Random Number</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Guess a number from 1 to 1000</h3>
<form method = "post">
    Enter guess: <input name = "guess" /><br /><br />
    <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Take Guess" />
    <input type = "reset" value = "Reset" /><br /><br />
    Your guess of <jsp:getProperty name = "randomGuessId" property="guess" />
    is <%= RandomGuess.guess(randomGuessId.getAnswer()) %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Java code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomGuess {
private int guess;
Random r = new Random();
private int low = 1;
private int high = 1000;
int R = r.nextInt(high-low) + low;

public int getGuess() {
    return guess;
}

public void setGuess(int newValue) {
    guess = newValue;
}

public String getAnswer() {
    String tooLow = "too low.";
    String tooHigh = "too high.";
    String correct = "correct!";
    if(guess == R) 
        return correct;
    else if(guess < R) 
        return tooLow;
    else
        return tooHigh;
}   
public static String guess(String s) {
    return s;
}
}
```

picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCmAK.png

Comment: It might be generating a fresh instantiation of `RandomGuess` each time you guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the page refreshes, a new instance of the bean is created - with a new number.

To preserve the number across calls, use a static field in your class.

---

Better yet, use JavaScript!

Answer (score 1):

Find complete program here:http://sickprogrammersarea.blogspot.in/2014/01/creating-number-guesser-in-jsp_8296.html

Hello friends this is a simple program of creating a number guesser in JSP....Have a look...

**Number.jsp:**

```
<html>
<head><title>Number Guesser</title></head>
<body>
<%              int num=(int)(Math.random()*100);        %>
<h2>Welcome To Number Guesser</h2>
<br><h3>Want To Check Your Guessing Power.....GIVE IT A TRY?????</h3>
<form name="guess" action="try.jsp?c=0" method="post">
<input type="text" name="val" value="<%=num %>" hidden>
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**try.jsp :**

```
<html>
<head><title>Number Guesser</title></head>
<body>
<%    String str=request.getParameter("val");
      boolean flag=true;      
      int num=Integer.parseInt(str);
      int c=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("c"));
      if(c!=0)
      {
                  int guess=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("guess"));
                  if(num==guess){
                              flag=false;
      %>
                  <h3>Congratulation...You Successes After <%=c%> attempts</h3>
                  <b>Want to Improve...<a href="Number.jsp">try again</a></b>
      <%       }else if(num>guess) { %>
                  <h3>You Guessed Lower...Try Bigger Number</h3>
      <%       }else{ %>       
                  <h3>You Guessed Higher...Try Smaller Number</h3>
      <%       }
      }
      if (flag) { c++; %>     
      <h3>I Guessed a Number between 1 to 100. Try To Guess..</h3>
      <form name="guess" action="try.jsp?c=<%= c%>" method="post">
      <input type="text" value="<%=num %>" name="val" hidden>
      Make Your Guess : <input type="text" name="guess" size=10 maxlength=3>
      <input type="submit" value="GO">
      </form>
      <% } %>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the user number back as a query parameter.

I'm guessing you are not too familiar with the MVC pattern or Spring, but there are plenty of resources available to get you quickly up and running.  I'll try to make a strip down demo later, if I remember.